# How to map json response to pojo

Tags: java, android, json, mapping, gson

What should I do to convert json response to object(pojo) using GSON lib? I have response from webservice:

```
{"responce":{"Result":"error","Message":"description"}}
```

and create POJO

```
public class ErrorResponse {

    private String result;
    private String message;
}
```

but

```
ErrorResponse errorResponse = (ErrorResponse) gson.fromJson(new String(responseBody), ErrorResponse.class);
```

gets an error

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 14

UPD

OK, i created

```
public class Wrapper {
    @SerializedName("Responce")
    private ErrorResponse response;
// get set
}


public class ErrorResponse {
    @SerializedName("Result")
    private String result;
    @SerializedName("Message")
    private String message;
// get set


 Wrapper wrapper = (Wrapper) gson.fromJson(new String(responseBody), Wrapper.class);
                        ErrorResponse errorResponse = wrapper.getResponse();
```

and finally I get NPE  errorResponse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is actually a JSON object containing a JSON object named `response`. That JSON object has the format of your Pojo.

So one option is to create that hierarchy in Java

```
public class Wrapper {
    private ErrorResponse response;
    // getters & setters
}
```

And deserialize that

```
Wrapper wrapper = (Wrapper) gson.fromJson(new String(responseBody), Wrapper.class);
ErrorResponse errorResponse = wrapper.getResponse();
```

An alternative is to parse the JSON into a `JsonElement` which you use to get the JSON object named `response` and convert that one. Use the following types from the Gson library:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
//...

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(json);
ErrorResponse response = gson.fromJson(jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("response"), ErrorResponse.class);
```

---

Note that your class' field names must match the JSON or vice versa. `result` vs `Result`. Or you can use `@SerializedName` to make it match

```
@SerializedName("Response")
private String response;
```

Comment: @Gorets Your field names don't match. `Responce` vs `responce`.

Comment: Error:(27, 29) java: org.springframework.boot.json.JsonParser is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Comment: @sapy You're not using the right `JsonParser`. The one in my answer is from Gson, not Spring boot.

Comment: @sapy It should've been obvious from the context of the question (_[...] using GSON lib_) and the code in my answer, but sure. I don't know why you assumed Spring...

Comment: I am a moderately experienced engineer. It was not obvious to me.

Comment: @sapy I'm not trying to insult you, it's just the question started with "What should I do to convert json response to object(pojo) using GSON lib?" In any case, I've updated my answer with `import` statement to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) online POJO generator to generate a POJO class from a JSON document or JSON schema with the help of GSON library. In the 'Annotation style' section, choose GSON. Once the zip file is created, extract it and add all the classes to your classpath.
Note: you will need to add GSON jars to your project.